# Why is the footer not going to the bottom of the page?

Tags: css

**Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W2UvH/1/**

Very simple implementation of a sticky footer that should stick to the bottom of the screen when there is less content height than the height of the screen. But if the height of the content extends beyond the height of the screen, then the footer should follow along with it.

I don't understand why my footer is stopping half way up the screen.

HTML:

```
<div id="Canvas">
 <div id="Container">
   <div id="Wrapper"> 
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="SiteFooter">
<p>Copyright © All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
        height: 100%;
}

#Canvas {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#Container {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #CCC;
    max-width: 802px;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
#Wrapper {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 730px;
    background-color: #999;
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1000px;
}
#SiteFooter {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9000;
    background-color: #FF00FF;
    height: 45px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #E0E0E0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that all your other elements are positions relative. So, not sure what your exact implementation is, but:

```
#SiteFooter {
    position: relative;
}
```

The above code should also do it for you.

Comment: This has worked out rather nicely! I also added a `margin-bottom: -45px;` to the `#Canvas` div because otherwise the footer seemed to be 45px off the bottom of the screen even though the `#Wrapper` was only filling a quarter of the screen in height.

Answer (score 0):

You want the position to be fixed, not absolute.

```
#SiteFooter {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Yes this makes it stick to the bottom of the screen, but not to bottom of the content. If the content exceeds the height of the screen, the footer still says in the same place. I want the footer to follow the content ONLY when the content exceeds the height of the screen.